# How to make a link open in new tab and Nofollow

Tags: html, css, blogger

I tried adding the `target="new"` and `target="_blank"` in the code, but it's not working.

```
<b:loop values='data:links' var='link'>
  <li expr:class='&quot;social-item &quot; + data:link.name'>
    <a expr:href='**data:link:target**'>
      <i class='item-icon fa'/>
      <div class='remove-count'>
        <data:link.name/>
      </div>
      <span class='item-text'>Followers</span> 
    </a>
  </li>
</b:loop>
```

Comment: it should working. by adding `target="_blank"` in open tag of `<a` element. so to troubleshot your case, can you provide live demo?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what's going on with your code but to make a link open in a new tab and nofollow you would do something like this.

```
<a href="" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" >Link Text</a>
```